# IF query with multiple choices

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

I have this batch-file where I'm moving files from one drive to another. The batch loops through the subdirs and moves everthying it finds. So far so good. Until today I did this in all but one subdir with an if-statement like this:

```
IF NOT !subdir! == SEW (
move part
)
```

Now I want to do this in all but two subdirs. How can I write my if-statement that is skipps those two dirs? In R, I could use somethind like

```
y <- c("SEW","SWW")
if(!x %in% y){
  move part
}
```

Is there something like the `%in%` command from R for a batch file? Or another solution to skip two subdirs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably the easiest method.

```
if not "!subdir!" == "SWW"  if not "!subdir!" == "SEW"  move part
```

Also, as per @LotlPings' comment, if however you are not sure about case, then perhaps include the `/I` option:

```
if /I "!subdir!" neq "SWW"  if /I "!subdir!" neq "SEW"  move part
```